# Method call in LINQ column

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have the following LINQ query:

```
//myRepository.GetClients(); returns an IQueriable<>
        var AllClients = myRepository.GetClients();


        var ClientReports = from c in FirmECFIs
                         select new ClientReport
                        {
                            FirmSerialNumber = c.SerialNumber,
                            FirmName = c.Name,
                            Year = c.Year,
                            Month = c.Month,
                            CustID = c.CustID,
                            TotalCount =myRepository.GetCount(c.SerialNumber, billingYear, billingMonth),
                            TotalPrice = "0"
                        };
```

I get an error that says "...has no supported translation to SQL"
Where I remove the method call from TotalCount column and assign a static value it works fine. Looks liek LINQ is not able to translate the method call to tSQL

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

### Source of GetCount() method:

```
        public int GetCount(int SerialNumber, string billingYear, string billingMonth)
    {
        var Count = CreateDataContext().myView.Where(c => c.SerialNumber == SerialNumber)
            .Where(c => c.Year == Convert.ToInt32(billingYear)).Where(c => c.Month == Convert.ToInt32(billingMonth));
        return Count.ToList().Count;
```

Comment: Why should LINQ be able to translate everyone's custom C# code into SQL?  If your code returns an `Expression<..>` and uses language constructs that are valid for LINQ-to-SQL, it should actually work.  Can you provide the source of `myRepository.GetCount`?

Comment: So if this is not possible then how can I handle this? If I do a loop after the query to set the TotalCounts it takes forever

Comment: You need to convert the logic in `myRepository.GetCount` into language compatible with LINQ-to-SQL, or embed the logic directly into your query.

Comment: OK take a look, I added the source for GetCount()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repository doesn't really do its job here very well - in fact it seems to be a very leaky abstraction that at best doesn't help you much (since you are still querying outside the repository).

One approach would be introducing a method `GetClientReports` to your repository that produces this result for you. Assuming this is just Linq to Sql underneath you can just use a nested query or join at that level.

Comment: Yea but even if I do it in repository I will have to include that method in a column to get the counts if I'm not willing to do it in a loop right?

Comment: @Sev: No, you can just use a nested query to determine the count for each item. Also you current implementation of that method has a big performance bug: instead of `Count.ToList().Count` use `Count()` otherwise you will materialize all rows!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I moved the LINQ query inside my repository and did a nested LINQ and it solved my problem.

Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

You can execute another SQL/LINQ query in that line, but you cannot call another C# function. It cannot translate that into SQL.